# django 1.5 Get latest records by Date

Tags: database, django, date, orm

I want to get all the records that have the latest date.

```
class Report(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   part = models.ForeignKey(Part,related_name="reports")
   this_week_use = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
   this_week_fail = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
   this_week_fail_percent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True,default=0.00)
   prev4_week_use = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
   prev4_week_fail = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
   prev4_week_fail_percent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True,default=0.00)
   platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform,related_name="reports")
   date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   class Meta:
    unique_together = ('part','platform','date')
```

---

I tried

```
rows = Report.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('date').filter(date=max_date))
```

Which resulted in no data

Answer (score 0):

Use `latest()` method

```
Report.objects.latest('date')
```

Comment: That gets me the latest date not all records with the latest date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by), it's available in `1.5`:

```
latest_rows = Report.objects.all().order_by('-date')
```

If you want any query in Your `report` model, by default ordered by this `date` field, then you can add this [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.ordering) on the meta section of your `Report` model.

```
class Report(models.Model):   
   class Meta:
      ordering = '-date'
```

Now you can make query without using `order_by` in your query, but with same result:

```
latest_rows = Report.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to make two queries, this should do it:

```
max_date = Report.objects.latest('date').date
qs = Report.objects.filter(date=max_date)
```